# How to manipulate the exception in __exit__ of a context manager?

Tags: python, python-2.x, contextmanager

I know it's bad style to re-raise an exception from within a context manager's `__exit__()` method. So, I'd like to tack an attribute on the instance which can carry contextual information that isn't available if I let the exception trickle through or if I catch it. This will avoid re-raising it.

The alternative to tacking the attribute on the exception would be to swallow the exception, set some state on the instance that doubles as the context manager in question and later check that state. Problem is that this would lead to a catch 22, wouldn't it? Since the exception means that execution inside the `with` block is being exited. There is no way to repeat the operation other than entering the `with` block again, right? So the instance in which I am trying to store the contextual information would go away once the `__exit__()` method returns.

So in short: how can I manipulate the actual exception that is pending (if it is, which I'll assume as given for this question) while in the `__exit__()` method?

Comment: Who says it is bad style? Context managers are an excellent way to transform an exception.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: actually **the documentation** states it is bad style, because it creates issues with nested context managers. And yes, for transforming and without nesting, good point.

Comment: You shouldn't re-raise the same exception (just returning `None` ensures the exception state is maintained), but you can raise a *new* exception.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: indeed. But the exception is fine, except that I need to carry some information over and up the call chain. So that's why re-raising would be bad style in my case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The context manager doesn't go away just because the block exits. You can preserve it in two ways:

1. Create the context manager first, assign it to a variable, then use `with` with that object:

   ```
   cm = ContextManager()
   with cm:
       # ....

   state = cm.attribute
   ```
2. Return the context manager itself from the `__enter__` method, use `with ... as ...` to bind that to a local name. That name is not unbound when `with` exits:

   ```
   with ContextManager() as cm:
       # ....

   state = cm.attribute
   ```

   where `ContextManager.__enter__` uses `return self`.

You can also set extra attributes on the exception itself; no need to re-raise the exception:

```
>>> class ContextManager(object):
...     def __enter__(self):
...         return self
...     def __exit__(self, tp, v, tb):
...         if tp is None: return
...         v.extra_attribute = 'foobar'
...         self.other_extra_attribute = 'spam-n-ham'
... 
>>> try:
...     with ContextManager() as cm:
...         raise ValueError('barfoo')
... except ValueError as ex:
...     print vars(ex)
... 
{'extra_attribute': 'foobar'}
>>> vars(cm)
{'other_extra_attribute': 'spam-n-ham'}
```

Here the exception was given an extra attribute that persisted all the way to the exception handler. In the above I also show that `cm` is still bound to the context manager.

Comment: My assumption was that your `v.extra_attribute = 'foobar'` and my `setattr(exc_value, 'extra_attribute', 'foobar')` would be functionally equivalent. However, using it gives `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'extra_attribute'`. Why is the value I get to see a `str` instance instead of an exception instance? It's inside the `__exit__()` method.

Comment: Are you raising a *string* exception? That's very much deprecated. Use object exceptions only (so subclasses of `BaseException`).

Comment: If you have no control over what exceptions are raised, you cannot set attributes on those exceptions that are old-style string exceptions. The standard library certainly doesn't raise these anymore, but I don't know what system you are using here. :-)

Comment: Last but not least, string exceptions support was removed entirely in Python 2.6, so if you are seeing this on 2.6 or 2.7 something else is wrong. Could you show me a gist or pastie that demonstrates the problem you are seeing? I certainly cannot reproduce any issues with `setattr()` in Python 2.7.

Comment: I am only raising any exceptions based on `BaseException` myself. But library code I call may raise something else. This is on Python 2.6 - I have no option of using something newer on the machines on which this runs (CentOS with 2.6, no 2.7 in vanilla installation). I'll try to come up with a piece of code demonstrating it, yes. Gimme some time.

Comment: @0xC0000022L: on 2.6 you won't be passed string exceptions, no. Can you print out the `repr()` of the first two arguments to `__exit__`?

Comment: Turns out 2.6 hands me a string exception. The string exception I am seeing is `"'Download' object has no attribute 'purge'"` and since I am not the one to convert an exception type to a string, I have to assume that this is passed to me by Python. Of course now I can go and fix the cause. But this was unexpected.

Comment: @0xC0000022L: the `__exit__` method is handed 3 arguments; type, value and traceback. What is the type in this case?

Comment: It is `str`. Is it possible that CentOS does something similar with Python as with the Linux kernel? I.e. mixing and matching as needed such that the version number doesn't really tell the truth? `python -V` reports `Python 2.6.6`.

Comment: @0xC0000022L: weird, because trying to *raise* a string exception in 2.6 raises a TypeError. Seeing what happens with a context manager in 2.6 based on different styles of raising exceptions.

Comment: @0xC0000022L: I had a hypothesis that doesn't hold. Perhaps CentOS *re-enabled* string exceptions in their 2.6 build rather than fix code that raises string exceptions? What does 'raise "foobar"` do when you type it into your Python?

Comment: the Python 2.6 on CentOS gives me the `TypeError` you described.

Comment: Weird then; in a debugger, when your context manager is passed the string exception, do you know if it was an actual exception being raised or something else called the `__exit__` manually? That value looks like an `AttributeError` message there.

Comment: I will have to try and create a minimal example that mimics the overall structure. Hope I can reproduce it this way. And yes, it looks like an `AttributeError`. Nothing in my code calls `__exit__()` explicitly, at least.

Comment: @0xC0000022L: looks like this is a Python 2.6 issue somewhere, see [\`exc\_value\` parameter from \`\_\_exit\_\_()\` (context manager) is string instead of Exception (Python 2.6)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30012062)

Comment: @0xC0000022L: Found the bug; this is an issue with the Python 2.6 implementation: http://bugs.python.org/issue7853