# exc_value parameter from __exit__() (context manager) is string instead of Exception (Python 2.6)

Tags: python, exception, python-2.6, contextmanager

I tried to mess around with context managers and got a bit surprised when running my code with Python 2.6. Indeed, the `exc_value` parameter seems to be a string instead of an exception.

A bit of code to hi-light this issue :

```
import sys

class contextmanager(object):

    def __enter__(self):
        pass

    def __exit__(self, type_, value, traceback):
        assert (type_ is None) == (value is None)
        if value is not None:
            print(type(value))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(sys.version_info)
    with contextmanager():
        __name_ # should trigger name exception
```

With Python 2.7 :

```
<type 'exceptions.NameError'>                       # GOOD
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_conman.py", line 17, in <module>
    __name_
NameError: name '__name_' is not defined
```

With Python 3.2 :

```
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=2, micro=3, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
<class 'NameError'>                       # GOOD
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_conman.py", line 17, in <module>
    __name_
NameError: name '__name_' is not defined
```

With Python 2.6 :

```
(2, 6, 7, 'final', 0)
<type 'str'>                       # BAD
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_conman.py", line 17, in <module>
    __name_
NameError: name '__name_' is not defined
```

My understanding is that `exc_value` should always be an exception.
Is there anything I did wrong ?
Is there anything I misunderstood ?
Is this a known issue ?

**References**

- [What’s New in Python 2.6 : PEP 343: The `with` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-343-the-with-statement)
- [Python 2 docs : `object.__exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback)`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__exit__)

Comment: And no, you didn't do anything wrong; the implementation in 2.6 just has this edge-case where the value passed in *can* be a string rather than the exception instance. I found the [bell that was ringing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26907175/how-to-manipulate-the-exception-in-exit-of-a-context-manager), but I didn't solve it then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug in Python 2.6, see [issue 7853](http://bugs.python.org/issue7853). It was fixed for Python 2.7a3 but never backported to the 2.6 branch.

In other words, you did nothing wrong, Python did.

Unfortunately, there's no real work-around other than to handle the fact that you don't have an exception instance in 2.6 but only the string value.